# How to Calculate avgLoad function, close connections and ensure availability function

Tags: python, oop

Help me out with this portion. I tried solving this but was unable to execute and have attached the same. Need help in calculating the avg load function, close connections function and ensure availability function. I know this is an assignment question and I even tried solving it and have posted that too. But still I got stuck at those functions, it would be great if anyone can help me out so that I can understand and implement it ahead.

LoadBalancing class will start with only one server available. When a connection gets added, it will randomly select a server to serve that connection, and then pass on the connection to the server. The LoadBalancing class also needs to keep track of the ongoing connections to be able to close them.

```
    class LoadBalancing:
def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the load balancing system with one server"""
    self.connections = {}
    self.servers = [Server()]

def add_connection(self, connection_id):
    """Randomly selects a server and adds a connection to it."""
    server = random.choice(self.servers)
    # Add the connection to the dictionary with the selected server
    # Add the connection to the server
    self.connections[connection_id] = server

def close_connection(self, connection_id):
    """Closes the connection on the server corresponding to connection_id."""
    # Find out the right server
    # Close the connection on the server
    # Remove the connection from the load balancer

def avg_load(self):
    """Calculates the average load of all servers"""
    # Sum the load of each server and divide by the amount of servers
    sum = 0
    for server in self.servers:
        sum += self.servers
    return sum/len(self.servers)

def ensure_availability(self):
    """If the average load is higher than 50, spin up a new server"""
    pass

def __str__(self):
    """Returns a string with the load for each server."""
    loads = [str(server) for server in self.servers]
    return "[{}]".format(",".join(loads))
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information on the below - 1. What is the definition of avg_load - Is this average of total connections per server i.e., total connections / number of servers ?   If this is true,  then you will end up with different servers having different loads so load balancing is going to be a difficult .       2.  Close_connections needs to remove the closed connections from self.connections.  Is this not being done for any specific reason ?

Comment: LoadBalancing class will start with only one server available. When a connection gets added, it will randomly select a server to serve that connection, and then pass on the connection to the server. The LoadBalancing class also needs to keep track of the ongoing connections to be able to close them.

Answer (score 3):

```
class LoadBalancing:
def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the load balancing system with one server"""
    self.connections = {}
    self.servers = [Server()]

def add_connection(self, connection_id):
    """Randomly selects a server and adds a connection to it."""
    server = random.choice(self.servers)
    # Add the connection to the dictionary with the selected server
    # Add the connection to the server
    self.connections[connection_id] = server
    server.add_connection(connection_id)
    self.ensure_availability()
    

def close_connection(self, connection_id):
    """Closes the connection on the the server corresponding to connection_id."""
    # Find out the right server
    # Close the connection on the server
    # Remove the connection from the load balancer
    for connection in self.connections.keys():
        if connection == connection_id:
            server_of_connection = self.connections[connection]
    server_of_connection.close_connection(connection_id)
    del self.connections[connection_id]
    

def avg_load(self):
    """Calculates the average load of all servers"""
    # Sum the load of each server and divide by the amount of servers
    result = 0
    loads = 0
    for server in self.servers:
        result += server.load()
        loads += 1
    return result/loads

def ensure_availability(self):
    """If the average load is higher than 50, spin up a new server"""
    if self.avg_load() >= 50:
        self.servers.append(Server())

def __str__(self):
    """Returns a string with the load for each server."""
    loads = [str(server) for server in self.servers]
    return "[{}]".format(",".join(loads))
```

**I hope this will help you because i tried to write it as clear as i can**

Answer (score 0):

```
> def add_connection(self, connection_id):
>     """Randomly selects a server and adds a connection to it."""
>     server = random.choice(self.servers)
>     # Add the connection to the dictionary with the selected server
>     # Add the connection to the server
>     self.connections[connection_id] = server
```

you should add the following code:

```
"server.add_connection(connection_id)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def avg_load(self):
    """Calculates the average load of all servers"""
    # Sum the load of each server and divide by the amount of servers
    sum = 0
    for server in self.servers:
        sum += self.servers
    return sum/len(self.servers)
```

Self.servers is a list, it cannot be added to a number (sum), thus you should refer to the load() function in part one of your assignment:

```
 sum += server.load()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ensure_availability(self):
    """If the average load is higher than 50, spin up a new server"""
    pass
```

Here, you haven't put any code to spin up a new server:

```
 if self.avg_load() > 50:
        self.servers.extend([Server()])
```